# Why do my Azure Service Bus sessions still exist even when there are no messages queued?

Tags: session, azureservicebus

I have a Session-Enabled Azure Service Bus queue.

I have some code that uses the WindowsAzure.ServiceBus NuGet package. (Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging assembly)

After processing several messages across two or three session IDs, marking those messages as complete using BrokeredMessage.Complete(), and also calling MessageSession.Close() on each of the sessions (I've verified this is happening) - all messages are consumed and the queue is clear.

However, when I then call QueueClient.GetMessageSessions() it returns 2 sessions as if they are not completed.

For the life of me I can't find the answer to this:
Is anybody aware of any condition/scenario that would keep a session "open" in Azure Service Bus even long after all messages have been consumed in the queue. At least as far as the QueueClient.GetMessageSessions() call is concerned?

I tried to reproduce the issue in a separate test, but failed to do so. Spawned up several random messages, did a chaos test where I try marking the sessions as closed, not marking them as closed, marking them as closed at the wrong times. Still, every time the test queue I spun up handles it fine and at the end of the "chaos" test returns the current number of sessions: 0.

In other words I can't reproduce this.

I decompiled the Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging DLL to see whats actually happening when calling QueueClient.GetMessageSessions() from the library perspective: Its actually sending off a TCP/IP GetMessageSessions command directly to the Azure Service Bus, and receiving the response from there. So this isn't something where the QueueClient instance is wrapping the call and doing something tricky to deduce how many sessions there are. This information is coming directly from Azure Service Bus.

I'm assuming that even if I am missing the call to MessageSession.Close() (and this is confirmed by my test) that the session will still be considered 'gone' if there are no messages in the queue for it to have a lock on. Especially after waiting long past any expiration dates/times in the queue configuration.

I'm still reading 2 sessions from QueueClient.GetSessions() against that queue even the next day.

Answer (score 1):

Oh *finally* I figured out what was going on.

In my code that was "breaking", I was setting some session state using MessageSession.SetState(Stream stream). I neglected to do the same thing in my test that I couldn't reproduce the problem with. Once I started doing that in the test, the problem was reproduced.

Summary:
Apparently when you run MessageSession.SetState(Stream stream) on a session and don't clear the state when you're done with the session, the QueueClient.GetMessageSessions() call will still return those sessions even after they are technically closed - at least a couple days later in my case.

At least for Azure Service Bus as of today, one must clear the state from a session if you don't want it showing up in the QueueClient.GetMessageSessions() response.

I haven't figured out just how long it takes for those sessions to 'disappear' from the results, if ever, if one chooses not to clear the state. I know in my cases its been two days and I still have sessions showing up.

Also note: You can't call QueueClient.GetMessageSessions() and then iterate through and call MessageSessions.SetState on those. The session returned from this call is actually just a SessionBrowser object underneath, so that method throws an exception. The state must be cleared in the initial SessionHandler.

Comment: This is from official documentation "*Session state remains as long as it isn't cleared up (returning null), even if all messages in a session are consumed.*" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions